# Lost my facebook account and all related pictures

Tags: facebook, account-security

I had to change my account. I must have been hacked. I received a message to go to facebook.com. also settings to turn off all sms.  I don't know what to do and facebook gave me a new account. I lost all my friends and photos.

Comment: I think this is something you need to ask Facebook support about. If you make a new account, of course all your friends and pictures will not be there.

Comment: Could you post the email you were sent from Facebook?  Facebook does not usually email you to tell you that you were hacked.  It is very likely that the email was a fake trying to get your credentials by forwarding you to a fake look alike site.

Comment: Who sent you the message?  How did facebook just give you a new account? I'm not aware that they would do such a thing. Maybe you overreacted and fell for a fake email claiming to be from facebook.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, facebook will not email you directly even in the event of a hack. What has most likely occurred, is someone obtained your facebook account primary email, which is easy for a determined attacker, then created a fake email (they could use hyperlink forging websites to make a link such as "security.facebook@facebook.com" or something similar) then emailed you with a malicious link warning you of some dire event that has made your account vulnerable.

If this is the type of message you recieved and you clicked that link, you could have very well given your credentials to the attacker who then stole your personal information, changed or deleted/deactivated your email account so you could not access it, and then took full control over your facebook account and deactivated it once they were done.

The reason the fake email suggested removing sms notifications or account security features is so the two-step authentication would not hinder the attacker logging in. In this, you were dupped. As I am sure the attacker may not have been skilled enough to access your mobile phone carrier's SS7 network and route the sms text message to their own phone.

With fake facebook emails, if you cannot tell a fake (you must understand that facebook does not usually email you directly) it is very likely you have been hacked. You will need to contact facebook support and fill them in on the details.

(EDIT)

Also, facebook did not "give" you a new account. It is likely the new account is a dummy account created by the attacker just make him/herself appear more legit. They may have included some kind of promise that all of your personal pictures and files you have uploaded would be transfered to the new account as well as your friends list. As a word of caution, I would quickly end the use of that new account asap. You may not know who has the access to that account and whatever you may do while using that account.

Comment: I think there is a lot of supposition in this, answer. For example, perhaps the OP created a new account by accident and it wasn't the attacker.

Comment: That could be the case. Since this is information security, I answered according to that. However, it would be very difficult to "accidentally " create a new account. It requires filling out at least 3-4 fields that have to be correct. It is also very much obvious that creating a new account is different than simply logging into an existing account, which means realistically speaking, your scenario is most likely not what occurred.